# Render React Component from name inside array map

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is either very simple or I am doing it completely wrong. I am a novice so please advise.

I am trying to show different components inside different tabs using Material UI using array map. The tabs are showing fine but the components do not render. Basically if the array label is 'Welcome', the tab name should be 'Welcome' and the Welcome component should show up and so on. Please help!

```
return (
<Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
  <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
    <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
    {fetchedCategories.map((category) => (
        <Tab key={category.label} label={category.label} />
      ))}
    </Tabs>
  </Box>
  {fetchedCategories.map((category, index) => {
      const Component=myComponents[category.label];
  })}
  {fetchedCategories.map((category, index) => (
    <TabPanel key={category.label} value={value} index={index}>           
      <Component label={category.label} />
    </TabPanel>
  ))}
</Box>
```

);

Here is my props & Component function:

```
interface ComponentProps {
    label: string;
    value?: number;
}

function Component (props: ComponentProps)
{
   const {label, value} = props;
   return myComponents[label];
}
const myComponents = {
    'Welcome': Welcome,
    'Salad/Soup': Welcome
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function Component({ label, value }: ComponentProps) {
  const [Comp, setComponent] = useState(<div />);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const LabelComp = myComponents[label];
    if (label && LabelComp) {
      setComponent(<LabelComp value={value} />); // <-- if you want to pass value to you component
    }
  }, [value, label]);
  return Comp;
}
```

And you will use it like:

```
const App = () => {
  return <Component label={"myComponentLabel"} value={"some value"} />;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this does not work either. Not really sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Here's a link with the full working example https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-meadow-0j4n0?file=/src/App.js